# A game that is going somewhere

Tags: python, python-3.x, game, tkinter

I'm working on a clicker game in Tkinter that is very different from [Bubble Blaster](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/174065/python-tkinter-game-bubble-blaster):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import *
from time import sleep
import math

extraCashCost = 50

class AppUI(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        self.saves = open("self.saves.log", "r")
        self.savesEdit = open("self.saves.log", "a")
        self.saveSring = ''.join(self.saves.read())

        Frame.__init__(self, master, relief=SUNKEN, bd=2)

        self.menubar = Menu(self)

        menu = Menu(self.menubar, tearoff=0)
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label="Game", menu=menu)
        menu.add_command(label="Open Store", command=lambda:storewin())
        menu.add_command(label="Browse Saves", command=lambda:showinfo("WIP", "This is a work in progress game"))

        menu = Menu(self.menubar, tearoff=0)
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=menu)
        menu.add_command(label="Open the developer window", command=lambda:devwin())

        try:
            self.master.config(menu=self.menubar)
        except AttributeError:
            # master is a toplevel window (Python 1.4/Tkinter 1.63)
            self.master.tk.call(master, "config", "-menu", self.menubar)

        self.money = 0
        self.cashGet = 1
        self.moneyShow = Label(root, text="$" + str(self.money))
        self.moneyGet = Button(root, text="Get Money!", command=lambda:cashin(self.cashGet))
        self.moneyGet.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        self.moneyShow.pack()

def cashin(cash):
    sleep(0.125)
    app.money += int(cash)
    app.moneyShow.config(text="$" + str(app.money))
def devcashadd(moneyz):
    app.money += int(moneyz)
    app.moneyShow.config(text="$" + str(app.money))
def devwin():
    dev = Tk()
    dl = Label(dev, text="Welcome to the developer window. \n Here you will have access to developer tools. \n This is available only in developer versions.").pack()
    mcl = Label(dev, text="Enter a number below and press the button under it to get free money!")
    mc = Entry(dev)
    mca = Button(dev, text="Get Money", command=lambda:devcashadd(mc.get())).pack()
    mc.pack()
    dev.mainloop()
def ec(cs):
    global extraCashCost
    if app.money >= extraCashCost:
        extraCashCost = math.ceil(extraCashCost * 2.2)
        app.money -= extraCashCost
        app.cashGet *= 1.6
        app.moneyShow.config(text="$" + str(app.money))
        cs.config(text="$" + str(extraCashCost))

def storewin():
    global extraCashCost
    store = Tk()
    extraCashShow = Label(store, text="$" + str(extraCashCost))
    extraCash = Button(store, text="More Money!", command=lambda:ec(extraCashShow))
    extraCashShow.pack()
    extraCash.pack()
    store.mainloop()

root = Tk()

app = AppUI(root)
app.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

It is going to be on [GitHub](https://github.com/xxxhypertextxxx/game) soon. Anything that could be changed to make it run faster?
And also, how can I put custom styles on the widgets?
Like background gradients, images, etc...

Comment: You might want to consider a better description of the code too. In my experience, the more context you give people to work with, the more likely they are to give you a good review.

Comment: Your question currently leaves some things to be desired. I'd recommend taking a look at [Simon's Guide to posting a good question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6429/31562). In particular, you could improve your description about the code, and add screenshots if possible. "Very different from Bubble Blaster" doesn't say much.

Answer (score 5):

**Don't use wildcard imports**

You had this same advice on your prior post. You apparently decided to ignore it. It doesn't make you look smarter.

Use `import tkinter as tk` if you must. But put some kind of prefix on Tk functions so that later readers of your code - including yourself months from now - will know when a function call or class reference is to an outside library:

```
class AppUI(Frame):   # ?

class AppUI(tk.Frame): # Aha!
```

**Use `super` in `__init__`**

Instead of calling `Frame.__init__` you should call `super` like so:

```
super().__init__(...)
```

See [this article by Raymond Hettinger](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) for more details.

**Don't hold open files you don't use**

You open files in `__init__` that you don't use and don't close. Avoid this. Instead, open/read/close or open/write/close them when you actually need to. The open operations are cheap compared to writing or reading from a file, and file handles are a scarce resource.

Also, doing your open/read or open/write at the same time allows you to use the preferred Python idiom, `with`, for your file I/O:

```
with open('savegame.txt', 'r') as save:
    savetext = save.read()
    ...
```

The `with` model handles errors well and automatically closes the resource when you're done, so you don't have to worry about it.

**Move your GUI code out of `__init__`**

Do what you need to do to set up member data, then delegate your GUI setup to another method. This makes **init** easier to understand, and you will likely find some code reuse once you have the "create a method" approach in mind.

**Use bound methods rather than global variables**

You have a callback like so:

```
def cashin(cash):
    ...
    app.money += int(cash)
```

But `app` is a global variable that points to your AppUI. How do you call it? With this line, set up in `__init__`:

```
    self.moneyGet = Button(root, text="Get Money!", command=lambda:cashin(self.cashGet))
```

So you're inside `self.__init__`, passing a function as a command to a button. But inside the function, you have to look up a global variable to figure out the value of `self`?

Try passing a bound method, or using a closure, for this kind of thing.

```
command=self.cashin  # no parens, it's a reference not a call
```

**Wrap your top-level code in a function**

There's a standard idiom for top-level code in Python. Use it!

```
def main():
    root = Tk()
    app = AppUI(root)
    app.pack()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Encapsulate!**

You pass `root` into `AppUI()` as a parameter. So why are you calling `root.mainloop()`? Why don't you encapsulate this in your `AppUI`?

```
app = AppUI()  # Let __init__ figure out to call tk.Tk()
app.run()      # app.run can call self.master.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

### Only create one instance `Tk`

You're creating more than one instance of `Tk` and you are calling `mainloop()` more than once. Tkinter is designed to have exactly one instance of `Tk()`, and exactly one `mainloop` running. If you need multiple windows, create instances of `Toplevel`.

### Don't call sleep

A GUI thread should never call `sleep`, since that's exactly what it does. Your entire UI will freeze. You're only doing it for a fraction of a second so it doesn't matter too much, but you should probably remove it.

I don't know what you're trying to accomplish with it, but if you just want some code to happen with a slight delay you can use `after` to schedule it to run in the future.